# karate.prevRequest does not work inside scenarios tagged @report=false

Tags: karate

As an example, this scenario will fail with an error, "cannot convert, not a json string: [type: NULL, value: null]":

@report=false
Scenario: POST request; 200 response
Given url 'http://localhost:8080'
And request { "id": "123" }
When method post
* def requestBody = karate.prevRequest.body
* json requestJson = requestBody

However, if you remove the @report=false tag (or set it to 'true'), the request body is captured just fine.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a bug, but can you please use the 1.0 series: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

All development is focusing on that, and as of now you should be able to test 0.9.9.RC4 - and if you still see an issue, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Retested against 0.9.9.RC4 - fixed!

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved with v0.9.9